# Converting text data to array which can be cleaned in python?

Tags: python, arduino, rfid

I am creating code for RFID card data gathering using arduino and python. I've worked out how to get arduino serial output to Python and save it to files named as the Card ID, which is great.

Now I need to clean the data, but I can't get my head around it.
Data here (don't understand how to intent here, FML):

```
Card UID: 0A 2E 45 35
PICC type: MIFARE 1KB
Sector Block   0  1  2  3   4  5  6  7   8  9 10 11  12 13 14 15  AccessBits
  15     63   00 00 00 00  00 00 FF 07  80 69 FF FF  FF FF FF FF  [ 0 0 1 ] 
         62   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
         61   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
         60   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
  14     59   00 00 00 00  00 00 FF 07  80 69 FF FF  FF FF FF FF  [ 0 0 1 ] 
         58   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
         57   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
         56   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
  13     55   00 00 00 00  00 00 FF 07  80 69 FF FF  FF FF FF FF  [ 0 0 1 ] 
         54   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
         53   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
         52   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
  12     51   00 00 00 00  00 00 FF 07  80 69 FF FF  FF FF FF FF  [ 0 0 1 ] 
         50   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
         49   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
         48   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
  11     47   00 00 00 00  00 00 FF 07  80 69 FF FF  FF FF FF FF  [ 0 0 1 ] 
         46   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
         45   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
         44   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
  10     43   00 00 00 00  00 00 FF 07  80 69 FF FF  FF FF FF FF  [ 0 0 1 ] 
         42   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
         41   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
         40   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
   9     39   00 00 00 00  00 00 FF 07  80 69 FF FF  FF FF FF FF  [ 0 0 1 ] 
         38   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
         37   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
         36   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
   8     35   00 00 00 00  00 00 FF 07  80 69 FF FF  FF FF FF FF  [ 0 0 1 ] 
         34   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
         33   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
         32   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
   7     31   00 00 00 00  00 00 FF 07  80 69 FF FF  FF FF FF FF  [ 0 0 1 ] 
         30   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
         29   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
         28   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
   6     27   00 00 00 00  00 00 FF 07  80 69 FF FF  FF FF FF FF  [ 0 0 1 ] 
         26   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
         25   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
         24   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
   5     23   00 00 00 00  00 00 FF 07  80 69 FF FF  FF FF FF FF  [ 0 0 1 ] 
         22   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
         21   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
         20   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
   4     19   00 00 00 00  00 00 FF 07  80 69 FF FF  FF FF FF FF  [ 0 0 1 ] 
         18   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
         17   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
         16   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
   3     15   00 00 00 00  00 00 FF 07  80 69 FF FF  FF FF FF FF  [ 0 0 1 ] 
         14   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
         13   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
         12   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
   2     11   00 00 00 00  00 00 FF 07  80 69 FF FF  FF FF FF FF  [ 0 0 1 ] 
         10   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
          9   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
          8   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
   1      7   00 00 00 00  00 00 FF 07  80 69 FF FF  FF FF FF FF  [ 0 0 1 ] 
          6   09 05 00 15  33 14 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
          5   73 73 73 73  73 73 73 73  73 73 73 73  73 73 42 95  [ 0 0 0 ] 
          4   20 20 5A 76  69 65 64 72  69 73 73 73  73 73 73 73  [ 0 0 0 ] 
   0      3   00 00 00 00  00 00 FF 07  80 69 FF FF  FF FF FF FF  [ 0 0 1 ] 
          2   73 73 73 73  73 73 73 73  73 73 73 73  73 73 42 95  [ 0 0 0 ] 
          1   73 73 73 73  73 73 73 73  73 73 73 73  73 73 73 73  [ 0 0 0 ] 
          0   0A 2E 45 35  54 88 04 00  85 00 B4 2E  F0 BB 6A A8  [ 0 0 0 ]
```

How can I convert it to equally spaced text in anarray shape, where columns and rows could be deleted with tabulate? I only need the HEX data and for now it is interpreted as a string with \n.

Comment: I'd use a regular expression per line.

Answer (score 1):

I am not exactly sure what you need, but it seems like you want a two dimensional list which contains hex data with columns and rows in order.

If that indeed is the case, I would do it like this:

```
data = """73 73 73 73  73 73 73 73  73 73 73 73  73 73 42 95  [ 0 0 0 ]
73 73 73 73  73 73 73 73  73 73 73 73  73 73 73 73  [ 0 0 0 ]
0A 2E 45 35  54 88 04 00  85 00 B4 2E  F0 BB 6A A8  [ 0 0 0 ]"""

lst = map(lambda x: x[:-11].replace("  "," ").split(" "),data.split("\n"))
print lst
```

**Explanation step by step:**

data is grouped as a multi-line string.

map is a function that lets you process all elements in a list with respect to the given function(left argument in map() ), in a list.

like:

```
lst = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
map(int, lst)
```

would give you a list of integers, instead of list of strings.
and equivalent to this:

```
map(lambda x: int(x), lst)
```

As you see all we do is define a function to change each item in a list.

which I did in the example, I changed every row by clipping the end with [:-11]. Thats why I used the map function, you can do it easily with a for loop of course. If you need explanation about split() in my solution, please mention.

which gives you;

```
[['73', '73', '73', '73', '73', '73', '73', '73', '73', '73', '73', '73', '73', '73', '42', '95'],
 ['73', '73', '73', '73', '73', '73', '73', '73', '73', '73', '73', '73', '73', '73', '73', '73'],
 ['0A', '2E', '45', '35', '54', '88', '04', '00', '85', '00', 'B4', '2E', 'F0', 'BB', '6A', 'A8']]
```

Now you can access the data with column and row operations and change it.

If it is not what you need, it is probably because you gave little detail about what you required, if you could give spesific detail i could help more of course.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll try to work with this, but it might not be what I need. The data is cluttered with additional information and I need to get rid of. The row and column numbering does not do me any good, all I need is the HEX stuff, and for me it is quite complicated to clean it out. As I understand this locates only a chunk of date, and converts it to array, but I'm not quite sure how it works. Could you please explain. "map(lambda x: x[:-11]" is bit too complex for me to grasp.

Comment: If the junk data is at the left and right of the hex line, consider using [:5], [:10] kind of notation, which I already used for the end of the line in the answer but didnt include the beginning of the line, which is enumerated rows. I will explain in a sec btw

Comment: I guess i got it:  lst = map(lambda q: q[14:-13].replace("  "," ").split(" "),x.split("\n")) gave me the result that I wanted. Now just need to remove top and bottom lines in the array. Any great way to do this? 

Thanks a Lot!

Comment: You need to remove top and bottom rows from that 2 dimensional array ? Try lst.pop(0) then lst.pop(-1).

Edit: Note that .pop() is an in-place method therefore doesn't return a new list, just changes the old one, therefore don't try to assign it like a new list. And try accepting the answer if it helps you with the case. I wish you success in your project.